# Docker container as default application

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I have Firefox nightly running in a container. I'm looking for a solution to configure it as my default browser application(ubuntu 18.04). 
So my question is, how to configure a Docker container as default system application in Ubuntu.

My docker command is:

```
docker run -d --net=host -v ~/:/home/firefox  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  \
  -e DISPLAY=unix:0 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --device /dev/snd \ 
  --group-add 29 -e PULSE_SERVER=unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native \ 
  -v /run/user/1000/pulse/native:/run/user/1000/pulse/native \
  firefox-nightly
```

I suppose I must create a new mime file, but not sure how to do it, to be able to create the container with all these parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to **create a new .desktop file** (e.g: /usr/share/applications/firefox-docker.desktop). 
I just copied the existing firefox.desktop and changed `Exec` sections with the command using docker (*)

Then use [xdg-utils](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-utils) (**) **configure it as default browser application**: 
`xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox-docker.desktop`.

---

*: To keep the .desktop file cleaner, you could create an executable file in system PATH (e.g: /usr/bin): **docker-firefox**:

```
xhost +
docker run --net=host -v ~/:/home/firefox  -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix  \
  -e DISPLAY=unix:0 -v /dev/shm:/dev/shm --device /dev/snd \ 
  --group-add 29 -e PULSE_SERVER=unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native \ 
  -v /run/user/1000/pulse/native:/run/user/1000/pulse/native \
  firefox-nightly $@
```

Note the `$@` at the end. And make it executable so it can be executed as a normal application.

**: The link is from Arch documentation, but it works in Ubuntu as well.

Comment: WoW! Your solution works like a charm. Thanks a lot. I've just two questions. What is the purpose of "xhost +"? Because I've removed it and it still works. And my other question is how it's possible that when I have a running firefox(docker), in my terminal, I select and click on a URL, and this URL opens in my running firefox!??? This is just perfect, better than expected but it's kind of magic for me as I don't understand how it's possible. For me, this should open a new firefox as this should create a new container. But no, this re-use my running firefox container.

Comment: 'xhost +' disables X server access control, which is required when executing from the command line. -> https://linux.die.net/man/1/xhost